# tikz variable value not change in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

Just for demo purpose, below logic only run into if clause but never run to else clause.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{10}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,4} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 0}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{1}
             \draw (0,0) circle (\i);
         }{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{0}
            \draw[red,line width=2pt] (0,0) circle (\i);
         }     
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe the variable \x define is wrong! how can I get the varialbe \x value changed each time the if check run? Now the if clause always think \x = 0. but actually I changed it in the if clause.

Comment: Use `\gdef\x{0}` to set `\x=0`. Read: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/435737/28557

Comment: You can actually use `[remember=\x as \x]`, e.g. `\foreach \i [remember=\x as \x] in {1,...,4} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 0}{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{1}
             \draw (0,0) circle (\i);
         }{
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{0}
            \draw[red,line width=2pt] (0,0) circle (\i);
         }     
    }`. This spares you from making `\x` global.

Comment: ... and `ifthen` is not needed here, `\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{10}
    \foreach \i [remember=\x as \x] in {1,...,4} {
        \ifnum\x=0
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{1}
             \draw (0,0) circle (\i);
  \else  
         \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\x}{0}
            \draw[red,line width=2pt] (0,0) circle (\i);
         \fi     
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works.